# Открытие div по нажатию с задержкой

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день, нужно есть скрипт открывающий скрытый див по нажатию на ссылку. Нужно сделать открытие с задержкой в 3сек, как это сделать? settimeout перед функцией не работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
<title>Задание 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onclick="show('div')">ссылка</a>
<div id="div">
Произвольный текст.
</div>

<script src="main2.js"></script>

</body>
```

JS

```
function show(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: setTimeout(show,3000), работает. как Вы делали?

Comment: Да, делал как в ответах указали, несколько раз пробовал, видимо где-то ошибался. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function show(id) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  },3000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function show(id) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
   }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="show('div')">ссылка</a>
<div id="div" style="display:none">
Произвольный текст.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант

```js
var link = document.querySelector('.link'),
    alert = document.querySelector('.alert');

link.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert.classList.add('alert-show');
}
```

```css
.alert {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;    
    padding: 8px 15px;
    background: tomato;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: 0s;
}
.alert-show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">ссылка</a>
<div class="alert">
    Произвольный текст.
</div>
```

Comment: ++ за preventDefault()